# Issue in executing Pig UDF

Tags: apache-pig

I wrote a UDF in pig where I want to pass all the tuple to the UDF function to filter .

```
REGISTER /home/ec2-user/FilterColumnsUDF-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
DEFINE  SampleFilterUDF SampleFilterUDF()

A = load 'hdfs://ip-XXXXX/pig/SampleUDF.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
B = SampleFilterUDF(A);
```

I am getting the error as

```
Cannot expand macro 'SampleFilterUDF'. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.
```

I tried In other way

```
B= foreach A generate SampleFilterUDF();
```

I want to know where I am doing wrong or any better way to do this ????

Comment: B= foreach A generate SampleFilterUDF(A.*);

Comment: maybe you are missing the full package namespace ?

Comment: yaah provide full package namespace in DEFINE!!